# Bootstrap modal form validtion not working

Tags: javascript

Have look at my code what is going wrong, my **Bootstrap** modal form validation is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        excluded: ':disabled',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            username: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Form Validation</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
  
<p class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>
</p>

<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Login" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">Login</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- The form is placed inside the body of modal -->
                <form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: shouldn't you add some description in text ?

Comment: try to run your `validation` code on **Bootstrap's** `shown.bs.modal` event. So, the code gets triggered when `Modal` gets active

Comment: i am new to bootstrap can u provide code snippet to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sholuld be `$('#loginForm').bootstrapValidator({...})` instead of 
`$('#loginForm').formValidation({...})` because you are using [bootstrapvalidator](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator) api ( bootstrapvalidator 0.5.3 ) older open source version of [formvalidation](https://github.com/formvalidation/formvalidation)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginForm').bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        excluded: ':disabled',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            username: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Form Validation</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
  
<p class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>
</p>

<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Login" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">Login</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- The form is placed inside the body of modal -->
                <form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   </body>
```

Comment: can u provide me the latest version api link for this code

Comment: link is already for formvalidation in answer .if you want to use commercial version of  bootstrapvalidator